# PHP: GOTO is Evil then How to show the Footer if some error arise at the Top

Tags: php

I was working on a large Web based Project. I was having an issue that I want to show the user Footer if some error arise or if record not found.

Let me explain.

Support, I have 3 PHP files named *header.php*, *body.php*, *footer.php*

In the **header.php**, I have added the top web page coding like meta tags, stylesheets etc.

In the **body.php**, I have added the content of web page to be shown on the base of different conditions. In this file there are also some codes that generate warnings like **Record not Found** against some condition of also generate some errors related to Query or Database etc.

I want to show the content in **footer.php** directly, If any error arise in this case.

I know you will say to use include function in the loop body and if error arise then use include function to show the footer.php but for how many times i have to write this line ? If there are almost 10k lines of codes in a single web page and there can be 100 of lines where such issues arise then within 100 times  i have to use include function to show footer.php and then exit function.

I was using GOTO function for this purpose and i use the section named *FOOTER_SECTION* and added this in footer.php code. & if any error or warning arise i was using GOTO FOOTER_SECTION so it show me footer.php content.

But instead of GOTO Function what should I use then to make it easy for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your framework can come to your rescue... if you have one. There’s a reason the MVC pattern is so popular.  If all requests are fed into a router, you can then catch exceptions at any time and immediately generate an error page.  (The error page can use the very same template as a regular page). With a template, there is no header.php, body.php, nor footer.php. You just stick the content into the template. period. No print or echo statements; you inject values into the template and print out the entire thing at the end.

Comment: This question is way too vague without any supporting code. Please edit your question and include the basic flow of your _body_ and _footer_ so we can have a basic idea of what your issue is.

Comment: @waterloomatt

I have explained more than the code here. The issue is not in the coding. The issue is in developing a string logic here. I mean what to use if we dont have to use GOTO when there are lots of coding in a single web page.

Comment: I understand you're using `goto` and are asking how to avoid it, but there really isn't a single answer; especially without seeing how your code is structured. This is the best guess I can come up with: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e0fc03688428699380c275b85d11029c836c13f6